# Is it possible to use a delimiter with Will_Paginate pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

In a Rails 4 app, I'm using the `will_paginate` and `will_paginate-bootstrap` gems:

```
=will_paginate @things, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails
```

[image]

Is it possible to specify a comma-delimiter in the pagination, so the higher pages would be listed as 30,115 and 30,116?

I'm aware of [number_with_delimiter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_delimiter) but I don't know how to use this with `will_paginate`.

Comment: Maybe an example here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/158.  If this works, you could override the `page_number` method and inherit everything else.

Comment: @Swards thanks, I'll check that out when I get a chance and will report back

Answer (score 0):

You can give the below code a try (put it in ApplicationHelper)

```
def page_entries_info(collection, options = {})
  raw super(collection, options).gsub(/\<b\>\d*\<\/b\> in total/, "<b>#{number_with_delimiter(collection.total_entries)}</b> in total")
end
```